# Why is drawing more cards a penalty?

Tags: conditions, ki-khanga

Negative conditions like Impaired and Disabled, force you to draw extra cards "on all checks" (KK 85, "Conditions").

But Talents, which are good, *grant* the ability to draw extra cards "when performing a task or in combat" (KK 23, "Talents").

Since so far as I can tell performing a task and making a check are the same mechanic (bottom of KK 79, "Resolution"), and combat uses the same basic structure, being able to draw more cards gives you more choices to play and thus is always good.

So why do negative conditions also force drawing extra cards?

Answer (score 5):

The resolution system as I have understood it is based on drawing cards to try and get as close to your Bust number as possible which is usually 21, but can be changed by the DM.

```
Your total is...                      The result is...
5+ points greater than ‘Bust Number’  Fumble
1-4 points greater than ‘Bust Number’ Failure
Bust Number                           High Success
1-4  points less than ‘Bust Number’   Full Success
5+  points less than ‘Bust Number’    Partial Success
```

Talents which grant the ability to draw more cards as needed in the KK resolution system allows you to draw cards and play if you wish to.

Whereas, being forced to draw cards I had on the other hand interpreted as being forced to draw and play, as this has an increased chance of pushing you past the Bust number.

You are basically playing blackjack/pontoon, and being forced to draw+play cards is often bad, where as having the choice to draw or not draw more, allows you to make the call.

This is how I have interpreted it, it may not be Rules as Written as it was a while since I looked over the book, but that is my understanding of why it is bad as you have to draw and play the cards. I will have to get the book back and have a reread.